# Angular Two-Way binding using NgModel not updating value

Tags: angular, select, ngmodel

I'm trying to implement a select box in Angular to be able to switch between orders. I'm also having a generic table that takes an api Url to get that specific order. The api url is built together within the ts file and contains the `orderId` which I'm trying to bind using `[(ngModel)]`. When I switch between `orderIds` using the select box, I want the table to be updated.

When I'm using the following implementation, the `{{orderId}}` is updating when I change the select box, but the `{{orderFilesApi}}` (and table data) isn't.

Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong?

`.ts` file:

```
@Input() orderId = '123';
@Output() orderFilesApi = this.serverUrl + '?' + 'orderid=' + this.orderId;

orders: Orders[] = [
   {value: '123', viewValue: 'ORDER1'},
   {value: '456', viewValue: 'ORDER2'}
];
```

`.html` file:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Change Order" [(ngModel)]="orderId">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let order of orders" [value]="order.value">
      {{order.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div>{{orderId}}</div>
<div>{{orderFilesApi}}</div>

<app-data-table
  [apiUrl]="orderFilesApi"
  [displayedColumns]="['name', 'type']">
</app-data-table>
```

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz with sample data?

Comment: `orderFilesApi` should not be value data type because you're decorating it with an `@Output()` , it should be a `EventEmitter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the code you posted there could be two reasons:

1. If

   `<app-data-table
   [apiUrl]="orderFilesApi"
   [displayedColumns]="['name', 'type']">
   </app-data-table>`

   in different html

   do like

   `this.orderFilesApi.emit(this.serverUrl + '?' + 'orderid=' + this.orderId);`

   in the change event.
2. If

   `<app-data-table
   [apiUrl]="orderFilesApi"
   [displayedColumns]="['name', 'type']">
   </app-data-table>`

   in same html

   change output property to normal one like  @output() orderFilesApi to simple property and set

   `this.orderFilesApi = this.serverUrl + '?' + 'orderid=' + this.orderId`

   in the change event.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the @Output parameter, I guess it was not needed here. The {{orderFilesApi}} is updating now but the table isn't. Maybe I need to refresh the page somehow?

Comment: Now in the app-data-table component you have to make the service call or call the method which is doing the service call. Do it in the ngOnChanges method.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function on the property onSelectionChange from MatSelect to update both your values (orderId and orderFilesApi)

Comment: Thanks, now the {{orderId}} and {{orderFilesApi}} are updating within the .html file, but the table is still not reloading with the correct values. The "orderFilesApi" is an url for a service to get data via http call.